# Ruby on Rails scaffolding error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to scaffold a model with the following command:

```
rails generate scaffold Ofertruck title:string country:string city:string lwh:string comment:text postalcode:integer weigth:decimal
```

the result I get in the migration file is the following:

```
class CreateOfertrucks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :ofertrucks do |t|
   t.string :title
   t.string city :country
   t.decimal :weigth

   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

What it generates is wrong, and it will give an error by
    bundle exec rake db:migrate

it is possible to see at line

```
t.string city :country
```

why it generates like this, since I made sure to put a space between every data base column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didnt give me an error, probably you are mistyped somewhere.

Delete it first:

```
#destroy

rails d scaffold Ofertruck title:string country:string city:string lwh:string comment:text postalcode:integer weigth:decimal
```

Try this one:

```
# Generate again

rails g scaffold ofertruck title country city lwh comment:text postalcode:integer weigth:decimal

#
```

Comment: Thanks! I  used rails g scaffold Ofertruck title country city lwh:string comment:text postalcode:integer weigth:decimal  and it worked.